# Why does this VBA code get a type mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code that is supposed to check the equality of two strings, but for some reason, I am still getting a type mismatch error.

```
If CStr(pf.PivotItems(q).Name) = CStr(Sheets("Dev Purposes").Range("A" + i).Value)
```

The `PivotItems.Name` is supposed to already be a string, and when I take out the `CStr` of that one it still gives me a type mismatch error. The `Range.Value` is supposed to yield a `Variant`, so that is why I added the `CStr`. The values are supposed to match exactly.

My issue was using the + instead of & for concat, thanks @BigBen

Comment: `Range("A" & i)`.... `&` should be used for concatenation, not `+`.

Comment: You're trying to add (`+`) `i` (probably an integer) to a string `"A"` instead of concatenating with `&`

Comment: `+` is not the most recommended concatenation operator. When it has to concatenate different variables type, VBA tries to transform one of them in what it looked more appropriate... If you insist to use `+`, try making both variables to be concatenated like string: `Range("A" + CStr(i)).value`. But this is a workaround which should not be used at all. I presented it only in order to give relevance to what I tried saying before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure here, but very often in excel I add + 0 to quantities I want to compare to a number or add & "", adding a zero length string, to quantities I want to compare to text.  These operations are not the identity operation, they are conversion to the desired type.  Perhaps if you used the & "" after both of them?